# Write a function that takes two lists, and returns True if the first list is the reverse of the same elements in the second list, and False otherwise

Tags: python, list, reverse

This is the code that I have written so far for Python. 
When I write `b[len(b)-1]`: it gives me the last number of the b list and accordingly when I put `a[0]` it gives me the first element (Sorry if this seems obvious, I'm trying to explain in detail what I am trying to do and what I understand of the code so I can get better help).
`b[len(b)-i]` -- My mentality for this part of my code is that I want to increase i by 1.

For example: 
`b[len(b)-1]`
`b[len(b)-2]`
`b[len(b)-3]` etc.

Similarly, I want to keep increase a by i 
`a[0]`
`a[1]`
`a[2]`

How would I go about on fixing my code? Any help will be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

```
def isReverse(a,b):
    if len(a)==len(b): #print True 
        for i in a and b: 
            if b[len(b)-i] == a[0+i]: 
                print True
            elif len(a)!=len(b):
                print False
```

Comment: Returning isn't the same as printing, that much is for sure.  That much alone needs to be fixed.

Comment: `def isReverse(a,b): return a==b[::-1]`

Comment: `[::-1]` is the only trick you need here. Remember that the 3rd argument taken is the step. If it's `-1`, it reverses the whole string. This is basically the way to check a palindrome or similar things. ;)

Comment: Another thing: `a and b` equals `a` if `a` not falsy else it equals `b`. I don't think this is what you intended.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I used [::-1] and it worked for my code. Can you please explain what the double :: does please!

Comment: Nevermind, I looked it up online and I have a general idea of what it does now. Thank you once again!

Comment: `[a:b:c]` is basically the (a) the starting index, (b) the ending index, and (c) is the step to take. When you use `[0]`, you are basically returning index 0, which is the first element. The length of your string or list, less 1, is the index of the last element. By not declaring it and just using `[::-1]`, it means, go from start to finish of string/list but step backwards. ;)

Comment: That was a much better explanation than what I found previously! Thank you.
I have another question: if you have a list = 1,2,3,4,5 and you wanted to go to index 3 for example, could you use the same logic to do this: [::3]? Or does the :: mean that it will go from the starting to finish and it would be better to just put [0:3]?

Comment: Don't be confused. :) The `[a:b:c]` "format" is called slicing. Look it up. If you want to go to index 3, go `[2]` instead. No more `:` needed. The only time you need the `:` is if you're slicing. Say, from `abcde`, you just need `bcd`. Your slice should be `[1:3]`. This is a shallow explanation. Slicing is a very powerful tool. The third part, the *step*, is needed only when you need to skip a certain way. Again with `abcde`, if all you need is `ace`, then go `[::2]`, which returns indices 0, 2, and 4 (a, c, and e). :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two lists, `alpha` and `beta`.

Your function returns the result of `alpha == reverse(beta)`.

Consider that reversing a list is merely writing this:  `beta[::-1]`.

Now, with that, we arrive at `alpha == beta[::-1]`.

To make it a complete function...you define the function, accept alpha and beta as arguments, and...return the result.

Comment: Thank you so much @Makoto! Just tried it out right now and it worked.